# Questions about the energy density and momentum density in linear media

Tags: energy, waves, momentum, classical-electrodynamics, poynting-vector

Precisely which energies are accounted for in the energy density of a linear medium given by $$u = \frac{1}{2}\left(\epsilon E^2 + \frac{1}{\mu}B^2\right)?$$ For example, is there a kinetic energy associated with each dipole's degree of freedom that is accounted for?

Does the Poynting vector, $$\mathbf{S} = \frac{1}{\mu}\left(\mathbf{E} \times\mathbf{B}\right),$$ represent the power per unit area for the same kind of energy that $u$ takes into account?

What momenta are accounted for in the momentum density $\mathbf{g} = \dfrac{1}{v^2}\mathbf{S}?$

Comment: Youa are asking about the energy momentum tensor in a polarizable medium?  This is difficult subject with a long and controversial history. You look up the "Abraham-Minkowski Controversy" on Wikipedia.

Comment: @mikestone Maybe? If it's that difficult, then why is it part of the undergraduate curriculum?

Comment: Mmm... the energy mometum tensor in media is not usually considered in such  depth as to answer "what kind of momentum".